# Bind DropDownList from List<Objects>

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one list of objects

```
var listOfUsr = new List<User>();

listOfUsr = GetUserByAgentId("some_id");

if (listOfUsr != null)
{
    DropDownList.DataSource = listOfModels;
    //DropDownList.DataTextField = "how to set value_from User.Name ?";
    //DropDownList.DataValueField = "how to set value_from User.ID ?";
    DropDownList.DataBind();
}
```

How can I set text and value field from object properties?

Comment: Please include what `listOfModels` is in your question.

Comment: Did you mean a Lookup ComboBox? The question is not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to set Column Name in `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`. 
In your case `Name` and `ID` are column names for your list object of user.

```
if (listOfUsr != null)
{
    DropDownList.DataSource = listOfModels;
    DropDownList.DataTextField = "Name";
    DropDownList.DataValueField = "ID";
    DropDownList.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this one:

```
DropDownList.DataTextField = "Name";
DropDownList.DataValueField = "ID";
```

I suppose, as it can be concluded from your comments, that an object of type `User` has two properties called `Name` and `ID` and these are the text and value correspondingly that you want to show.

Answer (score 1):

Use a ComboBox and  set **DropDownStyle =ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;**

Try this code:

```
  var listOfUsr = new List<User>();

  listOfUsr = GetUserByAgentId("some_id");

  comboBox1.DropDownStyle =ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
  comboBox1.DataSource=lstOfUsr;
  comboBox1.DisplayMember="Description";
```

You can also drag an object of type BindingSource and use it in this mode:

```
var listOfUsr = new List<User>();

listOfUsr = GetUserByAgentId("some_id");

bindingSourceListOfObject.DataSource = lstOfUsr;

comboBox1.DropDownStyle =ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
comboBox1.DataSource=bindingSourceListOfObject;
comboBox1.DisplayMember="Description";
```

With BindingSource have many possibilities and flexibility on complex scenario.